# How to re-cast a templated function from another templated function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am writing a solver for ordinary differential equations (ODE) and am trying to implement run time behavior that allows a user to select from multiple ODE solvers such as a forward Euler method, a second and fourth order Runge-Kutta method.  I am endeavoring to use a set of template functions so the user can pass variables to the solver as a map, where the key can either be an `int`, a `char` or a `std::string`.  In addition the associated value can be a `float` or a `double`.  In the member-function titled `ode_solver()` I need to set the variable `class_func` equal to one of the solver functions, which are `euler_method`, `rk2_method` or `rk4_method`; however, since those functions are not templated I am getting the message that `Variable 'class_func' with type auto has incompatible initializer of type <overloaded>`.  I am sure that this is due to C++ not allowing me do dynamically allocate a type to the functions.  The code is provided below.  Is there a way to enable the behavior I am attempting in this problem, or am I going to have to abandon templates and just hardcode the data types?  The area where the code is having problems is highlighted in all capital letters in the .hpp file.  I am using a C++17 compiler.

```
// main.cpp
#include "test.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

double func6(std::map<char, double> arr);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    ODESolver q;
    // Code inputs
    std::map<char, double> inputs;
    inputs['x'] = 2.0;
    inputs['y'] = g.e;

    double unc = 0.001;
    double tol = 0.0;
    double step_size = 0.1;
    double start = 2.0;
    double stop = 3.0;
    std::string func_name("Euler");
    std::tuple<std::vector<double>, std::vector<double>> res;
    res = q.new_ode_solver(step_size, start, stop, tol, func_name,
                           inputs, func6);
}

double func6(std::map<char, double> arr)
{
    return arr['y'] * MathKernels::logr(arr['y']) / arr['x'];
}
```

The header file is;

```
class ODESolver
{
public:

    template<class char_type, class real_type, class F>
    static inline std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>>
    ode_solver(real_type step_size, real_type start, real_type stop,
                   real_type error, std::string func_name,
                   std::map<char_type, real_type> &inputs,
                   const F& func)
    {
        // Verify that a correct function name was passed
        if (func_name != "Euler" and func_name != "RK2" and func_name != "RK4")
        {
            std::cout << "FATAL ERROR: ODE Solver Name must be 'Euler', 'RK2' or 'RK4'" << std::endl;
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Determine which ODE Solver to use
        // - THIS IS THE PROBLEM, THE COMPILER CANNOT DEDUCE
        //   THE TYPE FROM THE STATEMENT BELOW.
        auto class_func = &ODESolver::euler_method;

        std::tuple<real_type, real_type> res;
        std::vector<char_type> keys;
        std::vector<real_type> x_var;
        std::vector<real_type> y_var;

        keys = get_keys(inputs);
        std::cout << keys[0] << std::endl;

        // Solve ODE
        x_var.push_back(inputs[keys[0]]);
        y_var.push_back(inputs[keys[1]]);
        real_type time = start;
        while (time < stop)
        {
            res = class_func(func, step_size, inputs, keys, error);
            y_var.push_back(std::get<0>(res));
            step_size = std::get<1>(res);
            x_var.push_back(time);
            time += step_size;
            inputs[keys[0]] += step_size;
            inputs[keys[1]] = std::get<0>(res);
        }
        std::tuple<std::vector<real_type>, std::vector<real_type>> value(x_var, y_var);
        return value;
    }
// ================================================================

    template<class char_type, class real_type, class F>
    static inline std::tuple<real_type, real_type>
    euler_method(real_type step_size, std::map<char_type, real_type> inputs,
                 real_type keys, real_type error,
                 const F& func)
    {
        real_type dydx = func(inputs);
        real_type value = inputs[keys[1]] + step_size * dydx;
        std::tuple<real_type, real_type> vals(value, step_size);
        return vals;
    }
// ================================================================
// ================================================================

private:
    template<class char_type, class real_type>
    static inline std::vector<char_type> get_keys(std::map<char_type, real_type> &arr)
    {
        std::vector<char_type> keys;
        for (typename std::map<char_type, real_type>::iterator it = arr.begin();
             it != arr.end(); it++)
        {
            keys.push_back(it -> first);
        }
        return keys;
    }
};
```

Comment: presumably, In your real code, `class_func` is not always initialized with the same function pointer, but some actual logic instead (otherwise, you'd just use `euler_method()` directly). How that logic works is going to dictate which approach is best here. (mainly using a templated lambda/functor vs passing the method as a template template parameter)

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? `auto class_func = ODESolver::euler_method<char_type, real_type, F>;`

Comment: (Unrelated) In C++, don't include C headers with the `.h` suffix. Include them with the `c` prefix. `#include <cmath>`

Comment: Also, it looks to me like you should be templating the class instead of the functions? The functions all have the same template parameters. So it looks like the class should be templated with those parameters, not the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned you are trying to store address of a function but the assignment can not assign address of a function template!
Just specify the template arguments and since these arguments already exist in  `ode_solver` function template, (unless it is not desired to do so) you can use them directly in `euler_method` function template. quick fix looks like:

```
auto class_func = &ODESolver::euler_method<char_type, real_type, F>;
```

Also since it is in the same class:

```
auto class_func = &euler_method<char_type, real_type, F>;
```

Good luck!